# In PyCharm not able to see the buttons using Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, button

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

mybutton = Button(root, text="Click Me!)
mybutton.pack


root.mainloop
```

I am using this code but still I am not able to see the button in the window

Comment: First of all, you are missing a `"`. Second of all you need to use `mybutton.pack()` instead of `mybutton.pack`. Same goes for your `root.mainloop`. It should be `root.mainloop()`

Comment: As @TheLizzard said, () is needed to call the function. ```mainloop``` and geometry managers are functions. So you need to add a ```()```

Answer (score 0):

This code wouldn't execute neither **pack** method nor the **mainloop** because you are missing the parentheses when invoking functions. When you invoke functions without parentheses, you are only referencing to them instead of calling, so it means that the code inside the function will never be executed.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
mybutton = Button(root, text="Click me!")
mybutton.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Modifying your code as shown above should solve your issue.

Comment: You are missing the `import` statement from your code.